# CSS: change a single text character

Tags: css, fonts

Is there any way to modify one single font character in a text?

I have a webfont where the "-" character does not align correctly with the letters and I would like to move it upwards relative to the other characters.

Is there any way to acchieve this without switching to an image base solution?

Thanks!

Comment: With CSS other than [:first-letter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-letter) no, you'd need to either wrap the text in a span or parse it via JavaScript.

Comment: Or if supported by the font try one of the other line characters https://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/dashes.html

Comment: using a different line character is a really nice idea but sadly didn't help in this case. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap the character yourself, or alternatively use jQuery/Javascript to search for that character and wrap it.

Based on your question and some of your answers to people's questions. This works and has been tested.

```css
.moveMe { position: relative; top: -2px; }
```

```html
<p>Hyphen<span class="moveMe">-</span>moved.</p>
<p>Hyphen-unmoved.</p>
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks!
Sorry turtle - I think you meant the same thing but somehow the pen you made did not reflect what you wrote here so it didn't work for me. Btw. - the secret to the solution was the "relative" part, thats why everything I tried before did not work.

Comment: Yes the pen I linked was an out of date version. The one I added yesterday is working however I'm glad you got your issue resolved. 

Just remember that applying a span with an ID and then using that ID to format through CSS is a good way to target and style specific characters!

Comment: If it's going to be a style that's applied to multiple places, best practice is to use classes and not IDs. It's not kosher to have an ID declared more than a single time. While it will, of course, work the same as using a class, it's just bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

Yes wrap the character inside a `<span>` so it would look like `wo<span>r</span>d`. You can then give the span an #id and assign the font to the character inside the id.

The final output would look like `wo<span id="change-font">r</span>d`.

Using span and positioning the hyphen with `position: relative;`. Just change the number.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MKBaXN

Comment: This is exactly what I have tried - however there are not many things I can then actually use to manipulate the single character.

Adding a margin or padding applies to the entire line and moves all characters up. Same for line-height. I didn't come up with any ideas on how to manipulate it.

Comment: Can you put it in a pen? I can have a look at what you mean.

edit: I made a pen and put it in the answer.

Comment: It does not seem your solution worked - maybe this is browser related? (using firefox)
I have updated the pen to show the 2 versions of the text next to each other to compare. How can I make this work?

Comment: Sorry I didn't update the pen link. The one listed now is working. Just change the position relative to top or bottom and however many pixels you need.